# Profile Amazonka requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, haskell, query-optimization

I have a performance issue regarding [aws-lambda-haskell-runtime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aws-lambda-haskell-runtime) and Amazonka, in order to have a clearer view of the issue, I wonder if there are ways to get the time of each query.

I have looked for parameters in amazonka and http-client but it seems that `LogLevel` (even set to `Trace`), do not display these information.

Is there a way to display the time of each query for a `runAWST`, or should I wrap each `send`?

Comment: I would guess you should make your own wrapper.